# Wrong question closed of a pair of duplicates, best answer is in the closed question

Tags: discussion

Questions 106820 and 116654 ask the same question pertaining to a highly detailed synthetic chemistry problem. 116654 was closed as a duplicate but contains the much superior answer. I propose that 116654 be re-opened and 106820 closed.

Comment: I saw your flag, and I tend to agree, I was just a bit busy. Links would be really helpful for us btw!

Comment: Thanks for following through with the post here.

Answer (score 6):

The questions to be considered are:

- [How could you accomplish the following transformation in sufficient yield?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/106820/how-could-you-accomplish-the-following-transformation-in-sufficient-yield) (older)
- https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/116654/what-reagents-or-series-of-reactions-would-allow-for-selective-hydroxylation-of (newer)

Since the two questions are literally asking *exactly* the same thing, with exactly the same substrate and transformation to be accomplished, I have merged both. This consolidates comments and answers on one question. Since the action of merging is mostly 'commutative' in the sense that merging A into B yields the same results as merging B into A, I merged the newer question into the older one. (The question text of the older one is also marginally better explained, in my opinion.)

See also: [What is a "merged" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/what-is-a-merged-question).

I have also deleted the newer question, which means that you will need 10,000 reputation to view it.